# I can't figure out why I'm getting infinite loop

Tags: javascript, loops, infinite

I'm in the process of learning this language and I was asked by my teacher to write some code. Checked for all other posts about it and couldn't find the answer and I just don't understand why I'm getting infinite loop since the condition seems clear (to me at least haha): num1 has to be different from num2. The code is supposed to keep making the question in num2 until the user types the same number as num1.

```
var num1 = Number(prompt("Digite um número"))
console.log("Fight!")
arrayFinal = []
var num2 = Number(prompt("Que número o jogador 1 escolheu?"))

for (num1; num2 !== num1; num2) {
    arrayFinal.push(num2)
    console.log("O número chutado foi: ", num2)
    if (num2 > num1) {
        console.log("MISS! O número é menor!")
    } else if (num2 < num1) {
        console.log("MISS! O númenor é maior!")
    }
}
console.log("GAME OVER! O jogador 2 venceu! O número de tentativas foi: " +
    (arrayFinal.lenght + 1))
```

Comment: Here's a hint: do `num1` and `num2` ever change?

Comment: i think there is no termination condition in for loop. you are not changing num2 or num1

Comment: Also, think about what the different parts of the for loop actually do. The first part tells you how to initialize some variable (often using assignment like `i = 0`); the second part defines the "continue condition" (something like `i < 10`); the last part defines what the loop should do after each iteration (something using assignment again, like `i+=1`, in such a way that the "continue condition" may change from true to false). I suspect the first and last parts aren't doing what you think they are.

Comment: Yea, but I also tried simply taking them off, and adding something like "if (num1===num2) break" and it didn't change :( but thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

You want to ask the user for `num2` multiple times, hence its `prompt` should be in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop starts at `num1`. It also says that it will continue looping as long as `num2 !== num1`. But at the end of line 6, you just simply put `num2`, which does nothing to change num1. So, as long as `num1` was previously unequal to `num2`, it will always be unequal to `num2` and thus make the loop infinite.

You can declare `num2` as null outside the loop, then do the prompting inside the loop. That way, when `num2` equals `num1`, `num2 !== num1` returns `false`, and the loop will stop looping after that iteration. Otherwise, it will continue looping and prompting again and again... until the user inputs the same number as `num1`, then it will stop looping after the current iteration.

Also, Take lines 8-13 in the original code out of the loop, so that it does not get repeated as the code prompts repeatedly.

```
var num1 = Number(prompt("Digite um número"));
console.log("Fight!");
arrayFinal = [];

for (num1; num2 !== num1; num2) {
    var num2 = Number(prompt("Que número o jogador 1 escolheu?")); //dont forget 
    semicolon
    arrayFinal.push(num2);
    console.log("O número chutado foi: ", num2);
    if (num2 > num1) {
        console.log("MISS! O número é menor!");
    } else if (num2 < num1) {
        console.log("MISS! O númenor é maior!");
    }
}
console.log("GAME OVER! O jogador 2 venceu! O número de tentativas foi: " +
    (arrayFinal.length + 1));
```

Comment: Wow, I did not expect to get such an elaborate answer, thank you so much!